# Powershell dynamic Start-Job command to execute all powershell scripts in subfolders in parallel

Tags: powershell, start-job

For an important data migration, I would like to execute in parallel multiple scripts in side subfolders :

I did not succeed to do this :

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory

foreach($folder in $folders){
    $cmd = "powershell '$folder\script.ps1'"
    $job = start-job -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression $cmd}
}
```

[image: folder estructure]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: why are you calling your scripts with the CLI? `powershell '$folder\script.ps1'` ? this doesnt make sense, you're already executing the script from multi processes

Comment: each folder has a `script.ps1` inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You can use `Invoke-Command` for concurrent processing.</strike> Here's an example that may meet your requirements.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $folderPath = $_.FullName
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { .\script.ps1 $using:folderPath }
}

Get-Job | ForEach-Object {
    $result = Wait-Job $_ | Receive-Job
    Remove-Job $_
    $result
}
```

Comment: invoke command doesnt invoke in parallel in this answer. only when remoting it does.

Comment: You are right. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Passing the folder path _as an argument_ to each `.\script.ps1` call isn't what the question asks for, and it won't help. Instead, you must make sure that the folder path is incorporated into the path of the `script.ps1` script being invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Multithreaded in powershell 7:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | foreach-object -parallel {
  & $_\script.ps1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76335971/45375) is the simplest and best solution for [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, where [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) now has a `-Parallel` parameter for running [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) in parallel *threads*.

---

**A solution for *Windows PowerShell*** - the legacy PowerShell edition whose latest and *last* version is v5.1:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Directory |
 ForEach-Object {
   Start-Job { Set-Location -LiteralPath ($using:_).FullName; .\script.ps1 }
 } |
 Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Note:

- If the script needn't be run with its own directory as the working dir., the following `Start-Job` call will do:

  ```bash
  Start-Job { & (Join-Path ($using:_).FullName script.ps1) }
  ```
- If installing a module on demand is an option, consider installing the [`ThreadJob` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ThreadJob), whose [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) offers a *thread*-based and therefore *faster and more lightweight* alternative to the slow and resource-intensive *child-process*-based background jobs that [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Start-Job) creates.

  - Once installed, you can simply substitute `Start-ThreadJob` for `Start-Job` in the code above, given that `Start-ThreadJob` is compatible with all [job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs)-related cmdlets, such as [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Receive-Job).
  - Note that PowerShell (Core) 7+ *comes with* `Start-ThreadJob`, though the `ForEach-Object -Parallel` option - built on the same thread-based infrastructure - is often the simpler choice.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution, by using Start-Process, it answer my need. THank you every one